# Pipe the ouput of a hive query run on a remote machine to the local machine using python

Tags: python, csv, hive, subprocess, paramiko

All,

I'm trying to run a hive command ( run a query on a table) on a remote machine using ssh protocol ( remote address is xx.xxx.xxx.51 ) and then pipe the csv file to the local machine using python and pxssh (pexpect). I have it using subprocess and paramiko also.

1) **Code1 using pxssh**

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname, username, password = ('xx.xxx.xxx.51', 'username', 'passwd')
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    cmd = "hive -e 'use dbname; set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false ; select * from tablename limit 50'   >  ./myfile.csv"
    print cmd
    s.sendline(cmd) 
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print(s.before)        # print everything before the prompt. 
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```

Error:  It outputs a file myfile.csv on the remote server but not on the local machine.  I would like the csv file to be saved on my local machine from where the python script is being run.

The actual commmand is:

```
hive -e 'use dbname; set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false ; select * from tablename limit 50' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g '  >  ./myfile.csv"
```

But the options  `| sed 's/[\t]/,/g` give an error.

2) **Solution using subprocess**

```
import subprocess

command = "ssh username@xx.xxx.xxx.51  ls -tal "   # an example using ls -tal
print "submitting command", command
result = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
result.stdin.write('passwd\n')
result.stdin.flush()
print "got response"
response,err = result.communicate()
print response
```

3) **Solution using paramiko**

```
import paramiko

#Configuration for remote machine

server, username, password = ('xx.xxx.xxx.51', 'username', 'passwd')
ssh1 = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh1.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
#Loads the user's local known host file.
ssh1.connect(server, username=username, password=password)

# doing config for local machine
server2, username2, password2 = ('yy.yyy.yyy.112', 'username', 'passwd2')
ssh2 = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh2.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh2.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh2.connect(server2, username=username2, password=password2)

_, stdout2, _ = ssh2.exec_command('hostname')
hostname2 = stdout2.read()

command = " hive -e 'use dbname; set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false ; \
            select * from tablename limit 20' |   ssh  username@yy.yyy.yyy.112 'cat > myfile.csv' " 


#print cmd
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh1.exec_command(command)
print "output", ssh_stdout.read() #Reading output of the executed command
error = ssh_stderr.read()
#Reading the error stream of the executed command
print "err", error, len(error)
```

This gives the following error output:

```
output 
err Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

How did I pipe the results of the output of the hive query run on remote server to my local machine ?

Comment: You *really* need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you, and easier for you to help yourself.